# How to add texture paint over a material?

Tags: texturing

I've assigned a material to a sphere, and when I try to UV Unwrap it and texture paint it, my cursor applies paint correctly, but with an offset. When I click one area of the object, another area a couple inches over will be textured. How do I turn off this offset, or how else would I apply texture paint to an object with a material?

Comment: I realized what I did wrong, please ignore this post

Comment: Hello and welcome the site! Good to read that you have solved your problem! In this case, please write an answer to your question containing your solution and then accept this answer by clicking the check mark next to it after posting it. This way others who have the same problem and stumble across your post will also know your solution.